# Australian Mobile number regular expression validation needs to allow space in between number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

I need to validate the mobile number

- first text input starting with 04
- should be total 10 digits including 04(eg : 0412345678)

my input field is below

```
<form name="uploadForm">
<input type="tel" name="MobileNumber" id="MobileNumber" data-ng-model="ApplicationData.MobileNumber" required maxlength="14" data-ng-pattern="/^(0?4[0-9]{8}/\s)$/">
<span data-ng-show="uploadForm.MobileNumber.$error.pattern">Please enter a valid mobile number.</span>

<input type="tel" name="Number" id="Number" data-ng-model="ApplicationData.Number" required maxlength="14" data-ng-pattern="/(^1300\d{6}$)|(^1800\d{6}$)|(^0[2|3|7|8]{1}[0-9]{8}$)|(^04\d{2,3}\d{6}$)/">

<span data-ng-show="uploadForm.Number.$error.pattern">Please enter a valid mobile number.</span>

</form>
```

any one can you help me please ?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand this correctly, this is your regex pattern.

`^04[0-9]{8}$`

`^04` - starts with 04
`[0-9]{8}` - matches the next 8 digits
`$` - matches end of string

Comment: we can enter space in between the number e.g 0451 234 567 or space in between any number but maximum 14 character and should be 10 digits number starting with 04. I am not good at regular exp  can any one me ?

Comment: Edit your question with this requirement so it becomes more clearer.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679368/regex-optional-white-space-in-phone-number)

Comment: As of 2015 the prefix of 05 also indicates mobile (except for 055) -
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia#Mobile_phones

Comment: This could be optimised to `^0[45]\d{8}$`

Answer (score 5):

I think for your first question replace with this regexp. it accepts space in between number.

```
ng-pattern="/^04(\s?[0-9]{2}\s?)([0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2})$/"
```

for your second question, its quite long this is what i can come up with at this moment.

```
ng-pattern="/(^1300\s?([0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2})$)|(^1800\s?([0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2})$)|(^0[2|3|7|8]{1}[0-9]{8}$)|(^04(\s?[0-9]{2}\s?)([0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2})$)/"
```

any body have interest to modify/short this one.